# Box API download returning empty results

Tags: api, curl, box-api

I thought this should be easy, and maybe it is, and it's just me.
I want to test downloading files from my folder but getting empty html results:

> $ curl -L https://api.box.com/2.0/files/f_XXXXXXXX/content \ -H "Authorization: Bearer 8wAsXXXXXXXXX"

```html
<HEAD><TITLE>gw</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
GW
</body>
</html>
<HEAD><TITLE>gw</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
GW
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
curl -L https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/content  \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working properly for me.  Command execution might be affected by local configuration file `~/.curlrc`. Have you got this file? What is its content?